# Why does it take so long to load a row from a postgres table?

Tags: postgresql

This happens to be a rails app, but I've included the SQL generated, so it should be easy to see what I'm getting at.

I have a parent ->> children relationship in a postgres database.  There are about 5M children.  I can get all the ids (primary key) of a parents children in a short time (3s).  I can fetch a single child by id in a short time (32ms).

Why does it take too long (>5m) to fetch the first child of a parent?  What is postgres doing that it can't accomplish what feels to me like the same thing in just a few seconds?

How many children are there:

```
[3] pry(main)> Child.count
   (8832.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "children"
=> 5040608
```

How many children does the parent have:

```
[11] pry(main)> parent.children.count
   (76.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "children" WHERE "children"."parent_id" = $1  [["parent_id", 98107]]
=> 5213
```

Get all the ids of the parent's children:

```
[5] pry(main)> ids = parent.children.ids; nil
   (3184.6ms)  SELECT "children"."id" FROM "children" WHERE "children"."parent_id" = $1  [["parent_id", 98107]]
```

Load the first child of the parent using it's id from the list above:

```
[6] pry(main)> i = Child.find ids.first
  Child Load (31.7ms)  SELECT  "children".* FROM "children" WHERE "children"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7368558], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

And the explanation:

```
                                      QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.44..8.46 rows=1 width=1227)
   ->  Index Scan using children_pkey on children  (cost=0.44..8.46 rows=1 width=1227)
         Index Cond: (id = 7368558)
(3 rows)
```

Try to skip a step - just load the first child of the parent.  *Times out after 5m.*  Why?

```
[12] pry(main)> parent.children.first
  Child Load (308569.6ms)  SELECT  "children".* FROM "children" WHERE "children"."parent_id" = $1 ORDER BY "children"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["parent_id", 98107], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

I'm afraid I don't know how to get the query plan on this timed out query.  I'll poke at it...

Schema definition for the child table:

```
create_table "children", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "parent_id"
  t.integer "some_table_id"
  t.integer "another_table_id"
  t.date "start_date"
  t.date "end_date"
  t.integer "number_field", default: 0, null: false
  t.string "another_number_field", default: "USD", null: false
  t.integer "probably_unused", default: 0, null: false
  t.string "probably_unused_localized", default: "USD", null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.bigint "sum", default: 0, null: false
  t.integer "some_count", default: 0, null: false
  t.integer "session_count", default: 0, null: false
  t.integer "duration", default: 0, null: false
  t.string "some_cycle", null: false
  t.hstore "bad_hash", default: {}, null: false
  t.index ["parent_id", "some_table_id", "some_cycle"], name: "unique_to_parent_sim_and_cycle", unique: true
  t.index ["parent_id"], name: "index_children_on_parent_id"
  t.index ["another_table_id"], name: "index_children_on_another_table_id"
  t.index ["some_table_id"], name: "index_children_on_some_table_id"
  t.index ["start_date"], name: "index_children_on_start_date"
end
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a couple of things here:

In the first query you are not using an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT  "children".* FROM "children" 
WHERE "children"."id" = $1 
LIMIT $2  [["id", 7368558], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

but in the slow query you are:

```
SELECT  "children".* FROM "children" 
WHERE "children"."parent_id" = $1 
ORDER BY "children"."id" ASC 
LIMIT $2  [["parent_id", 98107], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

When you add the `ORDER BY` it first has to sort your children before it can pick from them.  If you omit that it will speed up, especially since it appears that children.id is not indexed.

Also, notice that in the first query your `WHERE` is `"children"."id"` and in the second by `"children"."parent_id"` which I assume is a typo?  Depending on what indexes you have (or don't) on those two columns you will also see a speed difference.

Comment: `[4] pry(main)> Child.where(id: ids.first).order(:id).first

      Child Load (38.2ms)  SELECT  "children".* FROM "children" WHERE "children"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "children"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 7368558], ["LIMIT", 1]]
`
No performance difference.  
``
children.id and parent_id are both indexed.  
``
The second query combines the notions of the first 2 queries - get the list of ids belonging to the parent (which is why the reference to parent_id) and return the first one from that list.
`damn this markdown`

Comment: You are still including the ORDER BY (which was not in the first two queries).  What happens when you drop it?